# dutch Bank account validation rule

Tags: javascript, html

Can anybody advise me how to make a validation rule for Dutch bank accounts?

So far i could only found this on web:

```
regex = /[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{3}/;
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
function dutchBankAccount(input) {
var regex = /[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{2}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{3}/;
if(input.value.toString().match(regex) && !(input.value == "")) {
    return true;
} else {
    input.click();
    input.style.border = '2px solid #F20056';
    return false;
}

}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<li><input type="text" id="anum" placeholder="Account Number" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onBlur="isValidAnum()" onFocus="emptyAnum('anum')"/></li>
```

Later on when I enter a dutch bank account I get error which I'm not supposed to get. So if you know how to solve this please help me.

Comment: I don't see how you could validate an account without some kind of protocol taking place between the client computer and a bank server.

Comment: What kind of validation do you mean? Just numeric (so as far as I can see 3 times 2 digits and one time 3 digits, all divided by a space), or do you want to make sure it's an existing dutch bank account number - ergo, satisfying the 'elfproef' in all cases but postbank/ing accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex syntax is incorrect.  Try something more like this:

```
var regex = /[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{3}/;
```

That matches strings like

```
32 01 28 192
```

Two digits followed by a space three times, then three digits. Whether that's what all Dutch bank accounts look like I don't know, though that seems like a small namespace for something like that.

(It occurs to me that `/(?:\d{2}\s){3}\d{3}/` should match the same strings and it's a little shorter.)

*edit* — To elaborate, the regex in the original code has some problems:

- The backslashe before each of the "\s" (space) characters is doubled, but it should not be. (That's assuming that Dutch bank account numbers don't actually look like "92\s31\28s\120")
- Putting a single character class shortcut ("\s") in square brackets is needlessly redundant
- Suffixing a regex element with "{1}" is needlessly redundant too

The real problem was the extra backslash. Also, speaking of needlessly redundant, there's no need to call ".toString()" on the value of an input element "value" attribute, and there's no need to make sure the value isn't the empty string if it has matched the pattern. In this case, an empty string cannot match the pattern, so that test is not necessary. Finally (promise), if you're just testing a regex against a string, the ".test()" method on the RegExp prototype is a little more efficient:

```
if (regex.test(input.value)) { // matched
  // ...
}
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize the dutch account number.

Comment: I believe the first number can be three digits. Aside from that, it is correct. There's a total of `10^10` (ie. 10 million) combinations if you add one more digit.

Comment: Saeed Does the Dutch account number actually look like the sample number in my answer? If @EdoDodo is correct, then the regex is incorrect and the "{2}" after the first "[0-9]" should be "{3}" ...

Comment: According to this page, the correct format is with three digits for the first part: http://www.ecbs.org/iban/netherlands-bank-account-number.html

Comment: @Pointy, yes the dutch bank account is like that, i give you another example 34 12 90 951, but the problem is that i cant use any spaces, its like the space has been disabled, and the problem is that I cant find any other example like this.

Comment: @pointy, in Netherlands you have different bank, and you have different sort of account number. for example we have here ING Bank which gives an account number of 7 digits like this: 23 46 767, also you have ABN Amro which gives you an account with 9 digits, like the example of yours. I changed the regex to this: var regex = /[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{1,3}/; and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Saeed: *do* check http://www.credit-card.be/BankAccount/ValidationRules.htm#NL_Validation